# Sistema eventos MVC / OO

Tags: php, mvc, framework, eventos

Estou escrevendo minha primeira aplicação PHP.
Pelo que andei estudando, optei por aprender Orientação a objeto e MVC.

estou construindo essa aplicação seguindo um livro que tenho, e ela está retornando o seguinte erro:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE) in C:\wamp\www\denis-manzetti\sys\class\class.calendar.inc.php on line 11
```

**sys/core/**

**[init.inc.php](http://pastebin.com/pKtbwW6v)**

**sys/config**
[**db-cred.inc.php**](http://pastebin.com/1306s2Fs)
**[class.event.inc.php](http://pastebin.com/wtsearQd)**

**sys/class**
[**class.event.inc.php**](http://pastebin.com/0fz96vkP)
[**class.db_connect.inc.php**](http://pastebin.com/bCpRcaBa)
[**class.calendar.inc.php**](http://pastebin.com/nzSAQ3JJ)

**public/**
**[index.php](http://pastebin.com/KNpejpvX)**

se alguém puder citar o que devo estudar, agradeço desde já, **abraços**

Comment: Repare a linha **11** do arquivo citado: `public function __construct( ... ){ private function _loadEventData( ... ) } }`. Você colocou o método *_loadEventData* dentro do *__construct*.

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\wamp\www\denis-manzetti\sys\class\class.db_connect.inc.php on line 7`

Comment: **db_connect.inc.php** linha 7: `protected function __construct( $dbo=NULL ){  if(is_object($db)) [...]`, você definiu `$dbo` e usou `$db`.

Answer (score 3):

Você está setando um atributo `public` e dentro deste atributo, está setando outro atributo que é o `private`, isso não pode acontecer, você não pode definir um atributo para uma função e dentro dela criar outra função com outro atributo.
Não sei como está no seu livro, mas normalmente isso gera este erro, o que você pode fazer é criar uma função sem atributos, do tipo `function`, se estiveres dentro de uma função que já tem uma atribuição.
Podes ver a compilação no `ideone`:

https://ideone.com/P1m7Nu //Código que gera o erro

https://ideone.com/EiPIQU  //Código que não gera o erro

Mas o método correto de fazer este seu algoritmo é separar o `_loadEventData` do método construtor, e chama-la através do operador `$this` ficando da seguinte forma:

```
class Calendar{
    private $_useDate;
    private $_m;
    private $_y;
    private $_daysInMonth;
    private $_startDay;

    private function _loadEventData($id=NULL)
    {
       //codigo
    }

    public function __construct($dbo=NULL, $_useDate=NULL)
    {
        $this->_loadEventData();
        //codigo
    }

}
```

Comment: Me de um exemplo em OOP de como você invoca `_loadEventData`.

Comment: https://ideone.com/mW0tnz

Comment: Agora sim :) Use esse ultimo comentário como resposta, pois ele sim é OOP e traz luz ao AP, e ponha o código aqui - não confie apenas em link externo.

Comment: Mais tarde com tempo eu irei atualizar ;)